# How to escape pipe character in Node js i18n plugin

Tags: node.js, internationalization

```
"title_team": "L'équipe - Découvrez ceux qui façonnent l'expérience shopping de demain ! | abc.com"
```

this is my language file and its rendering only the abc.com part of the string on node js project. How can I escape the pipe character (|) and print the whole string?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use a named parameter using mustache syntax like `"shopping de demain ! {{separator}} abc.com"` in the text, and then pass the pipe character as a parameter into the function: `{separator: "|"}`.
Or is there a better solution?